# Dynamic content page not being found

Tags: php, .htaccess, php-5.3

I got a single php page that needs to show different data when different urls are typed in or clicked on.

So what I did was create a content.php file.

In that file I put my html and basic stuff (including connection file etc) and add the following query:

```
//content
$content              = "SELECT * FROM `db_content` WHERE alias = '".$_GET['alias']."' ";
$contentcon           = $conn->query($content);
$contentcr            = array();
while ($contentcr[]  = $contentcon->fetch_array());
```

Then in my .htaccess I add the following line:

```
RewriteRule    ^nieuw/(.*).html website/content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

So every url that has nieuw/anytext.html should go to content.php and load the data that matches the alias. But when I type that url I get a page not found error.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This simple setup works. Make sure you enable RewriteEngine.

`.htaccess`:

```
# Enable rewriting.
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect nieuw to the content.php script
RewriteRule    ^nieuw/(.*).html$ website/content.php?alias=$1 [L]
```

`website/content.php` (you can replace this with your script, this dummy script shows you the `$_GET['alias']` variable):

```
<?php
echo $_GET['alias'];
?>
```

Now when I visit `nieuw/hallo_wereld.html` I see indeed `hallo_wereld`.

Comment: I already have the RewriteEngine on line added in my htaccess file. Still, this information could be useful to someone who forgot/didn't know about it.

Comment: Okay, so what is exactly in your Apache log files? Is the problem already resolved?